# Sqlite's Full Text Search on one column

Tags: sqlite, dictionary, full-text-search

I want to have a dictionary database with two columns `(word, definition)`. Is there any way to implement `fts` on only `word` column? Because the size of `definition` is quite large, beside no query will be performed on it anyway. Or should i split `word` into another table and apply `fts` on it?

Thank you :)

Comment: As i have read, by default fts apply for the whole table. I just asked if there is a way, but seem like no way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All columns of an FTS table are full-text-indexed.

If you want to index only a subset of your columns, you typically have a 'normal' table with all columns, and a 'shadow' FTS table with the indexed columns, linked with the `docid` to the real table's `rowid`.
To save some space, you can use an [external content table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2) in this case.

Comment: Thank for the help :)
Maybe i haven't read the documentation thoroughly. In addition to your suggestion, i found that there is `notindexed` option when create table using fts4.
Now i have two ways to go, will experiment with each.